# How can I get a RobotState of my robot?

Tags: java, robocode

Do you know, how can I get a [RobotState](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/docs/robocode/robocode/control/snapshot/RobotState.html) of my robot in Robocode? I would like to get an information for example, if my robot is active, alive, dead etc. In debug mode is it possible to see that information, but how can I get this in my code?

[image]

Comment: Post your code? You can use the methods listed in the link you gave. You can just call isAlive() to see if it's alive and so on... if rossRobot.isAlive() { doSomethingHere }

Comment: currentRobot.getState() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enum RobotState is only used in the core of RoboCode. There is no `getState()` method for your robot. (i digged through the [source code](https://github.com/robo-code/robocode))

However: you can get all theses state in other ways:

If your robot is hitting a wall, a HitWall event is fired. you can handle those events by overriding a method in your robot class:

```
@Override
public void onHitWall(HitWallEvent e)
{
    //your code
}
```

same with hitting a robot:

```
@Override
public void onHitRobot(HitRobotEvent e)
{
    //your code
}
```

if your robot dies:

```
@Override
public void onRobotDeath(RobotDeathEvent event) 
{
    //salute your warrior
    //your code
}
```

and if it's alive it should still loop in your runs method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    do {
         //here you do the normal stuff a robot does
    } while(true);
}
```

You can look at even more event methods in this interfaces:

- [robocode.IBasicEvents](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/docs/robocode/robocode/robotinterfaces/IBasicEvents.html)
- [robocode.IAdvancedEvents](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/docs/robocode/robocode/robotinterfaces/IAdvancedEvents.html)